# Como criar um data frame com resultados de uma função

Tags: r, funções

Criei uma função e gostaria de criar um data frame com resultados dessa função para algumas centenas de valores parâmetros. Fiz como no script abaixo, mas como podemos ver o script ficará gigante no caso de ter centenas de valores. Como posso fazer um script mais limpo para atingir o que pretendo?

```
z <- data.frame(k=c(runif(10, min=0, max=1)), 
              g=c(runif(10, min=0, max=1)), 
              h=c(runif(10, min=0, max=1)))
z

F <- function(t){
  k <- z$k
  g <- z$g
  h <- z$h
  l <- t*k+g+h  
  return(l)
}

oc1 <- F(1)
oc2 <- F(2)
oc3 <- F(3)

Tabela_final <- data.frame(Munic=c(1,2,3), 
                           FatorOP=c(oc1, oc2, oc3))

Tabela_final
```

Comment: Qual parte você quer substituir?

Answer (score 3):

Se o que você quer simplificar é o processo de juntar os resultados da função em um vetor para formar uma columna em `Tabela_final`, então você pode usar `lapply` com `do.call` para formar um vetor.

```
z <- data.frame(k=c(runif(10, min=0, max=1)), 
                g=c(runif(10, min=0, max=1)), 
                h=c(runif(10, min=0, max=1)))

fun_a <- function(t){
  k <- z$k
  g <- z$g
  h <- z$h
  l <- t*k+g+h  
  return(l)
}

# vetor com input para fun_a
vec <- c(1:3)

# use lapply com do.call para juntar o resultado de cada iteração
res_col <- do.call(c, lapply(seq_along(vec), function(x){
  fun_a(vec[[x]])
}))


Tabela_final <- data.frame(Munic = c(1:3), 
           FatorOP = res_col)
```